# in which processor or development board i can run ros?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

in which processor or development board  i can run ros ? do i need to buy sensors or other hardware from ros to run ros??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52449/in-which-processor-or-development-board--i-can-run-ros-?/) by [vikirobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/3978/vikirobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-01-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) on 2013-01-16**:
Please be more specific about what you want to achieve.

**Comment by [vikirobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/3978/vikirobot/) on 2013-01-16**:
i new to linux , can i run it intel atom board?? suggest me some low cost board

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-01-16**:
Yes definitely you can run on atom boards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can run it on a pc or mac. Generally when a development board can run Ubuntu it is possible to run ROS on it (with some effort). If you want to do some I/o than you need extra hardware. But you should research yourself some more not everything will be explained here..

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2013-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0